# How to count the number of majorizing points?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have the following problem which I would like to solve in faster than O(N^2) time: Given a set of N points of the form (x_i, y_i, z_i) for i ranging from 1 to N. Return a length N array whose jth element is the number of integers k for which x_k does not exceed x_j, y_k does not exceed y_j, and z_k does not exceed z_j.

Obviously it would be possible to simply iterate through all points in the set and then for each point check it against every other point in the set. But I feel there must be a faster way.

Comment: Are you familiar with segment trees ? You can try to solve it in 2d first by sorting points along one axis and building a segment tree along the other one using the first sort.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a speedup by using an [octtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree).

For a simple implementation, you can pick a random point as a pivot, then split your data into 8 sections depending on the binary decisions of whether it is `>` the pivot in the `x` direction, `y` direction, and `z` direction.  Each section records how many are in it, the max/min values in all 3 directions, its pivot, and its subtrees.

Recursively fill this out.

To get your counts you only need to descend the octtree to the point where a particular block is either in or not majorized.  This lets you skip most of the tree.

The tree is only `O(n log(n))` to build and size `O(n)`. Unfortunately for a given point you wind up still having to access all of the blocks in the the `x-y`, `x-z` and `y-z` planes for the octant majorized by the point in question.  On average I think that there are `O(n^(2/3))` of these.  Doing this for `n` points gives a total runtime of `O(n^(5/3))`.  This is better than `O(n^2)` but is probably not as much of a win as you were hoping for.  (In higher dimensions the win gets even less.)